# Class - Inner class and properties in Java

Tags: java

I have been trying to make a bottle class which include an inner class of beer. Why does the properties beer in outer class "bottle" not valid? such that "private 'beer' field is never assigned?

this is my code

```
public class Bottle {
    private Beer beer; //THE PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE//
    private double volume;


    public Bottle () {
    }

    public Beer getBeer {return beer;}
    public void Beer setBeer(Beer beer){return beer;}

    public double getVolume {return volume};
    public void setVolume (double volume) {return this.volume = volume;}


    public class Beer {
        private String brandName;
        private double strength;

        public Beer (String brandName, double strength) {
            this.brandName = brandName;
            this.strength = strength;
        }

        public String getbrandName() {return brandName;}
        public void setbrandName(String brandName) {return this.brandName = brandName;}
        public double getstrength() {return strength;}
        public void setstrength(double strength) {return this.strength = strength;}
    }
}
```

Comment: i don´t see any problems there, the only problems i do have is the continues error `can´t return value from void`.. Oh an i just saw you´re missing some round paranthesis here and there in a few of the method declerations.

Comment: `public void Beer setBeer(Beer beer){return beer;}` is one problem. Instead write `public void setBeer(Beer beer){ this.beer = beer; }`. Is a setter, not a getter and you cannot return multiple types at the same time.

Comment: @andreim oh yes, i change the return to `{this.beer = beer}` can you explain to me why is that needed? because that is already defined in the actual inner class of `public Beer`

Comment: @Kutam Whilst the inner class `Beer` is bound to the outer instance `Bottle` here it won´t set(assign) the variable `beer` by itself ;) You´re outter class doesn´t have any possible way to create a `Beer`(It can just set a `Beer` through `setBeer` with the corrected code). How would it create it? with which brand or which strength? In order for you´r `Bottle` to have a set `Beer` you need your `setBeer` to set the variable. Imagine you´d run your code without ever setting your `beer` variable but it having a set value. Wouldn´t it confuse you where the values would be coming from?

Comment: Yes I understand, because at first i thought that anything defined inside an inner class, the outer class just assumed what is defined inside in the inner for use. @SomeJavaGuy

Comment: @Kutam you have Bottle and Beer. Bottle has a Beer. Bottle has getter and setter for getting and setting the Beer instance. Having an inner class does not mean that a Bottle instance has an instance of Beer. Is just an inner class. Is better to keep classes separate in different files. Inner classes look odd in some contexts. For example is a good way to have inner classes in unit tests as you can simulate a BDD style. But in the majority of cases you just have two entities which have some relationship between them.

Answer (score 2):

Your code didn't have one problem but lots of problems. Mainly syntax errors. I corrected it to make it compile:

```
public class Bottle {

    private Beer beer = new Beer("Beck's", 5.1);
    private double volume;

    public Bottle () {
    }

    public Beer getBeer() { return beer; }
    public Beer setBeer(Beer beer) {return beer;}

    public double getVolume() { return volume; }
    public void setVolume(double volume) { this.volume = volume; }

    public class Beer {
        private String brandName;
        private double strength;

        public Beer (String brandName, double strength) {
            this.brandName = brandName;
            this.strength = strength;
        }

        public String getbrandName() {return brandName;}
        public void setbrandName(String brandName) { this.brandName = brandName;}
        public double getstrength() {return strength;}
        public void setstrength(double strength) { this.strength = strength;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can remove this `public Beer setBeer(Beer beer) {return beer;}` if you are not concerned with setting a beer instance.

Comment: Thanks, yup that helped. And I want to add alcoholcontent property to the bottle class. How do i use derived attribute from just the beer.strength?

Comment: so maybe like this `public double getAlcoholcontent(beer.strength) {return alcoholcontent;}
    public void setAlcoholcontent(double alcoholcontent) {return this.alcoholcontent = alcoholcontent;}`

Answer (score 0):

As Harmlezz said, you have some syntax errors. You are returning values in various `get` methods but mentioning the return type as `void`.

Once those errors are corrected, you can set a Beer object in a Bottle object like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bottle bottle = new Bottle();
        Beer beer = bottle.new Beer("La La Beer", 2);
        bottle.setBeer(beer);

        System.out.println(beer.getbrandName());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of error in your code.

You should do something like this

```
public class Bottle {
private Beer beer; 
private double volume;


public Bottle () {
}

public Beer getBeer() {
  return beer;
}
public void setBeer(Beer beer){
  this.beer = beer;
}

public double getVolume() {
  return volume;
}
public void setVolume (double volume) {
  this.volume = volume;
}


public class Beer {
    private String brandName;
    private double strength;

    public Beer (String brandName, double strength) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public String getbrandName() {
      return brandName;
    }
    public void setbrandName(String brandName) {
      this.brandName = brandName;
    }
    public double getstrength() {
      return strength;
    }
    public void setstrength(double strength) {
      this.strength = strength;

    }
}
}
```

Piece of advice first clear your basics like how to write function and all then jump into the code.

Comment: if i want to add `alcoholcontent` property in the outerclass `bottle` with derived attribute from `beer.strength` can I just do this `public double getAlcoholcontent(beer.strength) {return alcoholcontent;} public void setAlcoholcontent(double alcoholcontent) {return this.alcoholcontent = alcoholcontent;}`